I can't block the signal in c program
I wanted to verify that sigset would block the signal, so I built two sigactions, one for sending custom signals regularly, and one for the terminal to wait for the user to send the signal, but the strange thing is that my program can capture the signal sent by the user, But it does not block the custom signal
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void handler(int sig) {
    printf("ctrl c\n");
}

void handler1(int sig) {
    printf("user sig\n");
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction a;
    a.sa_handler = &handler;
    sigemptyset(&a.sa_mask);
    sigaddset(&a.sa_mask, SIGUSR1); 
    a.sa_flags = 0;

    struct sigaction b;
    b.sa_handler = &handler1;
    sigemptyset(&b.sa_mask); 
    b.sa_flags = 0;

    sigaction(SIGINT, &a, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &b, NULL);

    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
        raise(SIGUSR1);
    }

    return 0;
}

if i keep pressing ctrl+c , it should be
ctrl c
ctrl c
ctrl c

but actually
^Cctrl c
user sig
^Cctrl c
user sig
^Cctrl c
user sig
^Cctrl c
user sig

it means the signal SIGINT doesnt block the SIGUSR1
how can i do, is there some thing wrrong

The signal is only blocked during execution of the signal handler.

So what you mean is that since my signal processing function only has one print statement, it runs too fast, so it is not guaranteed to receive the SIGUSR1 signal during its operation, so the SIGUSR1 signal may not be blocked.

If you add a call sleep(3); before returning from the SIGINT handler, the signal blocking should be fairly obvious. You can also call raise(SIGUSR1); in the SIGINT handler to be sure that there is a SIGUSR1 signal pending and that it is being blocked.

Also, DO NOT call printf() from a signal handler. In fact, handling signals is rather tricky, as they are completely unsynchronized with anything happening on the process. Linux documents what can be called (man signal-safety) -- but, I'm not even sure I'd trust that completely. You can write into a pipe socket to notify your application about the signal; since my applications use boost::asio anyway, I just use its signal support as well.
